# What's a good server stat monitoring app with email alerts for Ubuntu LAMP server?

Tags: ubuntu, monitoring, lamp

I need to set up a server monitor application for a LAMP Ubuntu server that is easy to install and secure, doesn't use a lot of resources, and has an user-friendly interface, and perhaps more importantly, it has to have the ability to send email alerts.

I currenlty manage a web server, and I need to monitor the processor, memory, storage, and bandwidth. I usually use "htop" or "top," but I find them a bit difficult to understand. I also need the app to send me emails when certain problems occurs, such as when the CPU and/or RAM imcrease to X percentage for more than X number of minutes.

I also need to be able to access the stats from a web portal, which at the same time include protection so no one from the internet can access it.

I've been looking into Netdata standalone version and the cloud version, but I'm not yet conveince.

I wouuld like to know what's the stat monitoring app with email alerts the comunity recommends.

Comment: Look at [Nagios](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/nagios/), look here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/784781/system-monitoring-with-email-notifications